# zend framework 2 + doctrine: removing media with related Entity

Tags: optimization, doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework2, media

I've setup **ZF2** Skeleton Application with **Doctrine2**. My goal is to create simple News service with simple hierarchy.

```
  Category -> News -> Media (file)
```

I've setup all required relations for Category, News and Media (i.e. If News is deleted all related media is deleted from DB).

The **problem** is that media points to some file (located in file storage). I've implemented simple function that deletes all media related to News and then News it self.

```
  $news->deleteImg();
  $this->getEntityManager()->remove($news);
  $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

It feels that this is **wrong approach**.

Is there a way to bind delete file function to **Media Entity** that will be called automatically each time Media is removed directly or throught it's parents? (i.e. News or Category)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

It's pretty simple:

First add annotation before Media class

```
/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="media")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks  <- Add this line
 */
class Media
```

Then you need to add 2 functions for the class on **PreRemove** and **PostRemove**

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function storeFilenameForRemove()
{
    $this->temp = realpath($this->path);
}    

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeImg()
{
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        unlink($this->temp);
    }        
}
```

This functions will be fired: 1st before remove (to store file name) and second after Entity is removed from DB to remove related File.

You need also to define

```
private $temp;
```

That stores file name.

That's it. Now when you remove news or news category all related media files will be removed with the it's entity.